# Update Libreoffice and Delete Evolution mail client

Tags: gnome, libreoffice, email, postfix, evolution

I just update Libreoffice because it wasn't working properly by:
*snap install libreoffice*

But I install a newer version and keep the old one. And did not get the programs working yet.

So I update and install Libre office:
*sudo apt-get update*
*sudo apt-get install libreoffice**

But I found out that there was two versions of Libre office 6.0 and 6.2
So I decided to remove the older one:
*sudo apt-get remove libreoffice 6.0*

Here comes the problem:
I can not explain how but my mail client (Evolution) has gone. With all my job mails.

Can anyone please help me to recover all my mails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, when you uninstalled Libreoffice you uninstalled a lot more with it and probably also the ubuntu-desktop package.

Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to hopefully reinstall the unintentionally removed packages.